# Save field created in table HABTM

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

How I can save the date of creation of an element in CakePHP HABTM table, I tried to use the created field, as is normal in the other tables, but this does not work. 
I've also tried to saved one dateTime in my controller doing this:

```
$data = array ('created' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s "));
$this->model->UpdateAll($data,$conditions);
```

But it not works, It have one sql error in `H:I:S`

```
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:56:32'
```

Does anyone know any way to do this?

Comment: is `created` a `datetime` in your database?

Comment: yeah right I have a table with DateTime field created, as shown in the first tutorial cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the error in the database when inserting a date:

```
$time = "'". date (' Y-m-d H: i: s '). "'";
$data = array ('created' => $time);
$this-> model-> UpdateAll ($ data, $ conditions);
```

But I have not found the solution for the autocomplete create field in table HABTM

Comment: do you mean the automagic? `created` (and `modified`) needs to be a `datetime` and `NULL`. Cake will do the rest.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but it not work in HABTM table, when the element created is implicity of the creation of parent

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate model for your connection table. For instance if you have a model users and a model posts and users HABTM posts, then you also have a table usersposts. You can create the model userposts, assign to the user model a new relation hasMany userposts and finally from the users controller call:

`$data = array ('created' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $this->User->UsersPosts->save($data);`

Comment: Yes I try this! :) but i have this error  `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:56:32'`

Comment: Well I have done this `$this->model->UpdateAll($data,$conditions);` but it is the same

Comment: Maybe your database schema is not correct? Do you have a DATETIME field for `created` instead of a DATE field?

Comment: No, my database schema is correct, as shown in the tutorial. Only cakephp not insert the date when in a a table HABTM, when it is created from a view of one of its parent tables.